# Get product custom option in admin panel order detail page

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to get the product's custom option in admin panel along with order, it should work for the configurable products as well.

Also please let me know which files to change.

Answer (score 2):

You can change that by going through this file path

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml
```